# How to send data via ajax in a proper form

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

I want to send some data to my server via an ajax call. In the backend I run a django instance.
The data I want to send are the following:

1. Some points consisting of their xy coordinates plus a name
2. The type of analysis I want to do
3. Csrfmiddlewaretoken

My points are an object like this:

```
data = {name:{x:value, y:value}, name2:{x:value, y:value}} etc
```

thus an object of objects

my analysis is a string and my csrfmiddleware token is taken from the hidden input field django generates using the template tag.

In my ajax call my data parameter looks like this:

```
data:{'points':data,
      'analysis': $('select').val(),
      'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input [type="hidden"]').val()
     }
```

I want in my backend to be able to do the following

```
points = request.POST['points']
```

and then to be able to get the xy coordinates as follows

```
points['name']['x'] etc
```

But when I send data the above way my request.POST dictionary has the following items

```
{u'points['name']['x']:[u'450'],....} etc
```

While I wanted it to be something like

```
{points:{name:{x:value, y:value}}, {name2:{x:value, y:value:}}...}
```

How must I send the data to be sent the way I want?

Answer (score -1):

I Solved it this way by stringifying the object with the points

```
data:{'points':JSON.stringify(data),
  'analysis': $('select').val(),
  'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input [type="hidden"]').val()
 }
```

then on my backend

```
data = json.loads(request.POST['points'])
```

and voila, data is a python dictionary

Comment: why the negative vote? Shouldn't be a reason when downvoting?

Comment: Sorry...I don't have enough reps to down vote. This question is genuine. @Apostolos

Comment: My bad...Can't take it back...My appologies to u...Though your comment didn't give me a solution :)....Still I wish there was a reason for downvoting when downvoting as a feature of this site